# SetText does not display the expected String from a different Class

Tags: java, jlabel

I am attempting to set a JLabel's text to something on the applications compilation, the program compiles fine, I check my array to see that the values are in there, but the JLabel does not update. Made sure to initialize the JLabel.

FileHandling Class

```
import java.io.*;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.nio.file.*;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class FileHandling {

    private final String getWorkingDirectory = System.getProperty("user.dir"));
    private final String filePath = "/src/files/", fileName = "gameStats.json";
    private final String fullPath = getWorkingDirectory + filePath + fileName;

    private DieIntGUI dieIntGUI = new DieIntGUI("");

    private List<String> score;

    public void isCreated() throws IOException {

        if (!Files.exists(Paths.get(fullPath))) {
            Files.createFile(Paths.get(fullPath));
            BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(fullPath));
            bw.write("0|0");
            bw.close();
        } else {
            System.out.printf("File %s already exists\n", fileName);
        readFromFile();
        }

    }

    private void readFromFile() {
        try {
            score = Arrays.asList(Files.readAllLines(Paths.get(fullPath), Charset.defaultCharset()).get(0).split("\\|"));

            System.out.println(score);

            dieIntGUI.playerWins.setText("Player wins: " + score.get(0).toString());


        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

DieIntGUI Class

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.io.IOException;

public class DieIntGUI extends JFrame {

    public DieIntGUI(String title) {
        super(title);
        setSize(700, 700);
        getContentPane().setBackground(Color.white);
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        initComponents();
        add(panel);
        add(errorMessages, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        DieIntGUI frame = new DieIntGUI("Dice Game");
        frame.setVisible(true);
        FileHandling handle = new FileHandling();
        handle.isCreated();
    }

    private void initComponents() {
        panel = new JPanel();
        errorMessages = new JLabel();
        playerWins = new JLabel("");
        computerWins = new JLabel("");

        drawComponents();
    }


    private void drawComponents() {

        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();

        panel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        panel.setSize(700, 700);
        panel.setBackground(Color.white);

        gbc.gridx = 1;
        gbc.gridy = 1;
        gbc.weightx = 1;
        gbc.insets = new Insets(10,10,10,10);
        gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.EAST;
        panel.add(playerWins, gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 1;
        gbc.gridy = 2;
        gbc.weightx = 1;
        gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.EAST;
        panel.add(computerWins, gbc);


    }

    private JPanel panel;
    private JLabel errorMessages;
    public JLabel playerWins, computerWins;


}
```

Comment: Did you debug your code?

Comment: When I run it in debugging mode, there are no stack trace errors

Comment: if there are no stacktraces if you run it normally, there won't be any if you do run in debug. What I was recommending you to check is: does that setText get run? if so: what text is passed? how many times does it run? always with the text you expect? .... ?

Comment: If I use setText in the JLabel's origin class, it has no problem setting the text. However using the FileHandling class does not set the text, nothing is passed, it appears to be blank

Comment: does that code run, yes or no?

Comment: That's not what I ask. It might seem nothing happens, but still it runs, but with a blank String. so: does the code run? Did you add a breakpoint there?

Comment: I am not entirely sure how to add a breakpoint in order to debug the line of code. I haven't had that much experience with Java, if it helps, I'm using intellij

Comment: https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/debugging-your-first-java-application.html

Comment: Thanks for the documentation, the breakpoint condition error tells me that there is a NullPointerException

Comment: "breakpoint condition error"? this is nonsense. adding a breakpoint does not change your code, nor your flow. either there was a NPE before, or there isn't one now. Just check to see that everything is instantiated.

Comment: It has been instantiated as far as I can see, I checked the origin class and it is instantiated as: **playerWins = new JLabel("");**

Comment: Agree with @Stultuske with all he said. Finally, is there an NPE or not ? If there is one, you should be able to fix it easily. NPEs are basic mistakes.

Comment: Solved my error thank you Stultuske and @Dici